# What's the mariadb tarball different between glibc and non-glibc?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to download the mariadb with gzip type ,but I found that it has many files could been downloaded ,such as mariadb-10.2.6-linux-x86_64.tar.gz  ,mariadb-10.2.6-linux-glibc_214-x86_64.tar.gz (requires GLIBC_2.14+)   ,mariadb-10.2.6-linux-systemd-x86_64.tar.gz (for systems with systemd) .
I don't know what's different between them?

Comment: I prefere to use a package of your dist. Otherway you have a problem to update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that tarballs are *generic*, but not *universal*. Even though there seems to be many of them, there are still far less than supported systems and flavors. None of tarballs is guaranteed to work on any particular system. The common problem is absence of certain libraries which MariaDB server, client programs or plugins are linked with.

Back to the actual question, the main difference is highlighted in the package names/comments.

`mariadb-10.2.6-linux-glibc_214-x86_64.tar.gz (requires GLIBC_2.14+)` -- the binaries built on reasonably modern systems. The package most likely contains more plugins/engines, because some of them have requirements for modern compilers and libraries; but it can only be run on systems that have globc 2.14 or higher.

`mariadb-10.2.6-linux-systemd-x86_64.tar.gz` (for systems with systemd) -- the package with systemd support. It's important if you actually install the service and run it this way. If you just keep the binaries locally and start them manually, it shouldn't matter.

`mariadb-10.2.6-linux-x86_64.tar.gz` -- the package provided mostly for legacy/compatibility purposes, for older systems which are still not EOL-ed. Generally it has somewhat better chances to be successfully run on an arbitrary system, but you need to check whether it contains everything you need, as it might be not the case.